# Create a text encoding conversion service in Automator

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, automator, encoding

I was trying to make a Finder service to easily convert text encoding of some files. Because the default charset for Simplified Chinese in Windows is the Chinese national standard GB18030 (not the UTF-8 used on Mac).

With some help from the answers at [services - Automator Get Filename of Selected File - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121483/automator-get-filename-of-selected-file), I set up **Service receives selected: *Files or folders* in:*Finder***

Then, I made this Shell script in Automator:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    iconv -f gb18030 -t utf-8 f > f.new
done
```

However, when I run the service when selecting `f`, I don't see the newly created `f.new` in Finder. I guess I have set the output path wrong. But I don't know what is the right way to fix it.

[image: Automator screenshot]

Comment: To make it work, the **Pass input:** in the procedure should be **as arguments** instead of **to stdin**.

Comment: I've modified my answer to address a comment made by Gordon Davisson and suggest you use the modified answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    iconv -f gb18030 -t utf-8 f > f.new
done
```

To:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    if [[ ! $(basename "$f") =~ .*\..* ]]; then
        iconv -f gb18030 -t utf-8 < "$f" > "${f}-new"
    else
        iconv -f gb18030 -t utf-8 < "$f" > "${f%.*}-new.${f##*.}"
    fi
done
```

And set **Pass input:** to **as arguments** on the **Run Shell Script** *action*.

---

To address the comment made by Gordon Davisson to handle a *filename* with no *extension*, I've modified the code in my answer above.

The *code* tests the *filename* portion of the *fully qualified pathname* passed to the **Run Sell Script** *action* using a *regex* to see if it has an extension, or more literally a `.` as part of the *filename*, and if there is no `.` in the *filename* it process the *if branch*, otherwise it processes the *else branch*.

Also note that using a *glob* instead of a *regex*, e.g.:

```
if [[ ! $(base name "$f") == *.* ]]; then
```

Would also work to test for an extension. Either way the new *fully qualified pathname* will appropriately follow one of these two examples:

- `/path/to/filename` becomes: `/path/to/filename-new`
- `/path/to/filename.ext` becomes: `/path/to/filename-new.ext`

Note: This answer assumes *fully qualified pathnames* do not contain null characters and or carriage returns and or linefeeds. IMO Proper *pathnames* do not contains such characters and I will not test for them.

Comment: @jackxujh, I updated my answer. Seems you need to direct the input file into the command and then redirect the output to the new file. The old and new file should be in the same location now. As well as what you noted in your comment to your question.

Comment: After I changed the *pass parameters* setting, the previous edit of the answer (without `<`) started to work fine. And then I saw you added the `<` mark. And it also works!

Comment: Now the service makes `file.txt.new` with converted text encoding when run, but ideally `file-new.txt` would be even better. Is that possible too? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it actually works either way however it does need to be **Pass input: as arguments**, which I didn't look at in your picture, because I automatically use that when running a `for` _loop_.

Comment: @jackxujh, I've updated my answer to address your comment "Now the service makes file.txt.new with converted text encoding when run, but ideally file-new.txt would be even better. Is that possible too?"

Comment: I appreciate the help and patience! I'm sorry for troubling you with this simple *regex* practice, which I just learned more about from your answer.

Comment: @jackxujh, No problem, that's what were here for, to help and learn! :)  BTW Read the Parameter Expansion section in the BASH manual page.

Comment: `"${f%.*}-new.${f#*.}"` only works on filenames with exactly one period character (in directories that *don't* have periods in the name). Doing this right is surprisingly hard, but `"${f%.*}-new.${f##*.}"` (note the double-`#`) handles multiple periods properly (though it still gets confused by filenames without periods).

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, That's good to know. If you want to edit that into the answer feel free to do so.

Comment: @user3439894 I went ahead and expanded it to handle pretty much anything -- feel free to revert if you think that's too much change from your version.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, Thanks for pointing out an issue in the code! I have modified the answer to address your 1st comment in a different manner then your edit, sorry. BTW I had accidentally left out a `#` in my original modified answer to address jackxujh wanting `-new` to be before the extension, it truly was a typo as I changed `"${filename##*.}"` to `"${f#*.}"` when of course it should have been `"${f##*.}"`. However even with it, it would fail if the filename didn't have an extension. So testing for it should have been a part of the code and I've changed it to a method I prefer. Thanks again!